# async.Future async.Completer - how to "continue" if an error

Tags: dart

Some help with the following would be appreciated. I am writing some console test programs, and I want to be able to enter some parameters from the terminal (I don't want to use command line arguments - too many parameters). I have tried some variations, but I cannot find how to accomplish this. The following is the latest version of my test for terminal input. The problem with this program is that if an error is encountered, the Completer closes automatically, and I want to continue from either the Main() or from fGetNumber() function. While I can see why this program doesn't work, it illustrates what I need to achieve - re-enter the number, but I cannot find how to achieve that. If a valid number is entered, there is no problem. If an invalid number is entered, I cannot find out how to re-enter the number.

The code is as follows, and the problem I have is highlighted by "//////////" :

```dart
import "dart:async" as async;
import "dart:io";

void main() {
  fGetNumber("Enter Nr of Iterations : ", 0, 999999)
  .then((int iIters){   
    print ("In Main : Iterations selected = ${iIters}");
    if (iIters == null) {
      print ("In Main: Invalid Number of iterations : ${iIters}.");
    } else {
      fProcessData(iIters);
    }
    print ("Main Completed");       
  });
 }

async.Future<int> fGetNumber(String sPrompt, int iMin, int iMax) {
  print ("In fGetNumber");
  int iIters  = 0; 
  async.Completer<int> oCompleter = new async.Completer();

  while (!oCompleter.isCompleted) { ///////////   This loop does not work ///////  
    return fGetUserInput(sPrompt).then((String sIters) {
      iIters = int.parse(sIters);
      if (iIters < iMin || iIters > iMax) throw new Exception("Invalid");        
      oCompleter.complete(iIters);
      return oCompleter.future;
    }).catchError((_) => print ("Invalid - number must be from ${iMin} to ${iMax}")
    ).whenComplete(() => print ("fGetNumber - whenComplete"));// always gets here
  }
  print ("In fGetNumber (at end of function)");     //// it never gets here
}

async.Future<String>  fGetUserInput(String sPrompt) {
  print ("In fGetUserInput");
  async.Completer<String> oCompleter = new async.Completer(); 

  stdout.write(sPrompt);
  async.Stream<String> oStream = stdin.transform(new StringDecoder());
  async.StreamSubscription oSub;
  oSub = oStream.listen((String sData) {
    oCompleter.complete("$sData");
    oSub.cancel();
  });

  return oCompleter.future;
}

void fProcessData(int iIters) {
  print ("In fProcessData");
  for (int iPos = 1; iPos <= iIters; iPos++ ) {
    if (iPos%100 == 0) print ("Processed = ${iPos}");
  }
  print ("In fProcessData - completed ${iIters}");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> // This loop does not work

Of course it does - you enter it exactly once, where you immediately return and therefore leave the loop and method.

> // always gets here

That's because `whenComplete()` always gets called, on success or on error.

> // it never gets here

Because you already returned out of the method.

**So what can be done?**

The easiest way would be to not rely on `fGetUserInput()`. Listen to `stdin` in `fGetNumber` and only complete the completer / cancel the subscription if the input is valid:

```dart
async.Future<int> fGetNumber(String sPrompt, int iMin, int iMax) {

  print ("In fGetNumber");
  async.Completer<String> oCompleter = new async.Completer(); 

  stdout.write(sPrompt);
  async.Stream<String> oStream = stdin.transform(new StringDecoder());
  async.StreamSubscription oSub;
  oSub = oStream.listen((String sData) {
    try {
      int iIters = int.parse(sData);
      if (iIters < iMin || iIters > iMax) throw new Exception("Invalid"); 
      oCompleter.complete(iIters);
      oSub.cancel();
    } catch(e) {
      print("Invalid - number must be from ${iMin} to ${iMax}");
      stdout.write(sPrompt);
    }
  });

  return oCompleter.future;
}
```

**Are there alternatives?**

Of course. There are likely many, many ways to do this. This one for example:

```dart
async.Future<int> fGetNumber(String sPrompt, int iMin, int iMax) {
  print ("In fGetNumber");
  async.Completer<int> oCompleter = new async.Completer();
  fGetUserInput(sPrompt, oCompleter, (String sIters) {
    try {
      int iIters = int.parse(sIters);
      if (iIters < iMin || iIters > iMax) throw new Exception("Invalid");
      return iIters;
    } catch(e) {
      print ("Invalid - number must be from ${iMin} to ${iMax}");
      stdout.write(sPrompt);
    }
    return null;
  });
  return oCompleter.future;
}

void fGetUserInput(String sPrompt, async.Completer oCompleter, dynamic inputValidator(String sData)) {
  print ("In fGetUserInput");
  stdout.write(sPrompt);
  async.Stream<String> oStream = stdin.transform(new StringDecoder());
  async.StreamSubscription oSub;
  oSub = oStream.listen((String sData) {
    var d = inputValidator(sData);
    if(d != null) {
      oCompleter.complete(d);
      oSub.cancel();
    }
  });
}
```

If you really feel there should be something addressed by the Dart team, you could write a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list). But the `Completer` is designed to only be completed once. Whatever code you write, you can't just loop to complete it again and again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did already know that, however, I want a "standard" input function, and other functions that "call" that function - eg. string, integer, currency, etc. However, if what you have posted is the only way to achieve "it", I will accept the answer, however, I think that "this" needs to be addressed by "Dart". However, maybe I'm wrong. Async IMHO needs what has been posted as "await", or something else to address this scenario.

Comment: @BrianOh I said "the easiest", not "the only one". I'm editing the answer to show another approach. There are likely even more alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps the ability to disable autocomplete of a Completer would be a "solution". Then "my" loop would work (?). Why have "Complete" if there is autocomplete? I'm probably over-simplifying the "problem", or at least what I see as a problem.

Comment: Where is there any autocomplete? `Completer`s are completed when calling `complete()`. That's a conscious method call. Your loop still wouldn't work, because no async operation is performed while you endlessly loop.

Comment: @BrianOh Anyway, it's a fact there is no way to block processing until a `Future` completes, which would be a requirement for your loop. There are easy ways (code #1), and there are dynamic ways (code #2) to do what you want. If you think this isn't enough, file a feature request. I can't change that.

Comment: quote "Completers are completed when calling complete(). That's a conscious method call". I don't believe that is the case. When there is an error (non numeric or range), an exception is thrown, and the code for the completer is not executed. When control returns to MAIN, the value returned is null (if an error). There are other situations where I believe it is not possible to achieve what is needed because of what appears to me to be an "anomaly". I will post that separately.

Comment: @BrianOh That appears so because you don't return the `Future` of `fGetNumber`s `oCompleter`, but from `fGetUserInput`. Both handlers are called by the `oCompleter.complete()` in `fGetUserInput`. Return the right `Future` and you'll see that `fProcessData` is never called when your input is invalid.

Comment: or rather, `print ("In Main : Iterations selected = ${iIters}");` will never be printed (your code wouldn't call fProcessData anyway)

Comment: I'm not sure what point you are making there Mario. As I see it, I cannot achieve what I need to achieve. In this case, it can be "fixed" by changing the code and doing the test at the point of data entry. There are other situations where that cannot be done, and I will post that situation separately. But maybe there is an acceptable solution to that scenario - I'm just learning async and futures. I'll make the other post once I document it with a test program. There seems to me to be something missing with loops involving Futures (IMHO).

Comment: @BrianOh My point is that the "anomaly" is no anomaly at all. And the whole point of Futures is that there is no need for any loop. You can still achieve anything with Futures - again, see the code above. You are stuck thinking synchronously. While I agree that sync I/O would be very nice, there isn't any, so you need to adapt, even if this isn't your "style".